# What's the syntax error in below PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL query from PHP file is as follows :

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO $this->mTableName(contact_list_name, contact_list_desc, ";  
        $sql =." contact_list_created_date) VALUE('".clean($form_data['contact_list_name']). "' ";
        $sql =." ,'".clean($form_data['contact_list_name'])."', unix_timestamp()) ";
```

It's giving me the following error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in ContactList.php on line 60
```

I tried to change many things but it didn't work for me. Can you help me in resolving this syntactical error and building a proper query? Thanks in advance. One more thing instead of Values I'm using  Value as this is preconfigured in my system. So there is no issue with the word Value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Should be $sql .= not $sql =.

$sql .=" contact_list_created_date) VALUE('".clean($form_data['contact_list_name']). "' ";
$sql .=" ,'".clean($form_data['contact_list_name'])."', unix_timestamp()) ";
```

Comment: +1, simply because you have the best eyes in the world!

Comment: @som: Thanks for your help. As Dave said you got really awesome eyes. I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks for your compliment.

Answer (score 3):

It shud be

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO $this->mTableName(contact_list_name, contact_list_desc, ";  
    $sql.=" contact_list_created_date) VALUE('".clean($form_data['contact_list_name']). "' ";
    $sql.=" ,'".clean($form_data['contact_list_name'])."', unix_timestamp()) ";
```

It is actually

```
.=
```

and not

```
=.
```

Answer (score 2):

you are appending in 1 variable, it should be like:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO $this->mTableName(contact_list_name, contact_list_desc, ";  
$sql .= " contact_list_created_date) VALUE('".clean($form_data['contact_list_name']). "' ";
$sql .= " ,'".clean($form_data['contact_list_name'])."', unix_timestamp())
```